# React-redux : Initiate state with an axios request, avoid undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, jsx

Im using React-redux. I've got my reducer 'sellerHandler.jsx", i would like to initiate his state with an axios call. My problem is : my state is undefinied, i guess because axios its an async function.

```
    import axios from "axios";
    
    function getUser() {
        axios   
        .get("/xhr/seller/get")
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.seller);
            return data.seller;
        })
    }
    
    
    const initialState = { seller: getUser() }
    console.log(initialState.seller);
    
    function sellerHandler(state = initialState, action) {
        let nextState;
    
    
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'REPLACE_SELLER':
                nextState = {
                    ...state,
                    seller: action.seller
                }
                return nextState;
    
            case 'RESET_SELLER':
                nextState = {
                    ...state,
                    seller: null
                }
                return nextState;
    
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    
    export default sellerHandler;
```

the console.log inside the axios call output this :

```
{id: 2426, firstname: "Martin", lastname: "Bosco"}
```

when the one outside output 'undefined'

When my app is loaded for the first time, I want my sellerHandler (reducer) to initialize with a seed value, which is the result returned by my axios query

How I can make this code work ?

**SOLUTION :**
Use HOC in order to initiate my reducer state before any action in my app

Comment: I guess you want your values in reducer. but you haven't dispatched anything from action, how would it responded there?

Comment: When my app is loaded for the first time, i want my sellerReducer to have a default value, which is the value returned by my axios call.

Comment: Have you used redux before? Because the way you are just returning the value from function will not trigger any action creators.

Comment: Okay i see what you are doing here. but the thing is axios is async request. it will request server to get data and then it will respond. so you might not have these value on exact time. you should try HOC instead.

Comment: Yep i knew it was something about async call, i don't know what is HOC, i will check this, thx mate

Comment: Don't try this. it will not work. Your thinking is correct unless you are retriving data from server. you might need higher order component which will perform on your first app render and it will load components only after you get these details.

Comment: Ok ! I don't know how to use theses HOC, i think im going to try another way to initiate this state, directly in my main component for example with an action dispatch

Comment: As you said you need these values before any action happens, you should use HOC. else it will be like a patch that can put you in trouble anytime.